Flutter How to make paging at Future<void>
I have data for 100 items coming from my API server and the data is fine with no problem with it, but I'm trying to make it show 20 items every time I get to the end of the list but it keeps loading without stopping that's my code.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels == scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent &&
              hasMore) {
            fetchItems();
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: fetchItems(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
            } else if (categoyItems == null || categoyItems!.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(child: Text('No states available'));
            } else {
              return GridView.custom(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                gridDelegate: SliverStairedGridDelegate(
                  mainAxisSpacing: 6,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  pattern: [
                    const StairedGridTile(0.53, 0.8),
                    const StairedGridTile(0.470, 0.8),
                    const StairedGridTile(0.470, 0.8),
                    const StairedGridTile(0.53, 0.8),
                  ],
                ),
                childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  childCount: categoyItems!.length + (hasMore ? 1 : 0),
                  (context, index) {
                    if (index == categoyItems?.length) {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    final item = categoyItems![index];
                    return Container(....);
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

and my function that get items from my API server
  List<CategoryItems>? categoyItems = [];
  int offset = 0;
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool hasMore = true;
  int totalCount = 0;
  bool hasData = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchItems();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> fetchItems() async {
    if (isLoading) return;

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      PaginatedCategoryItems paginatedItems = await AppMethods()
          .fetchCategoryItems(widget.type!, widget.state!, offset);

        setState(() {
          categoyItems!.addAll(paginatedItems.items);
          offset += paginatedItems.items.length;
          totalCount = paginatedItems.totalCount;
          isLoading = false;
          hasMore = categoyItems!.length < totalCount;
          hasData = true;
        });
      
    } catch (err) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(err);
      }
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

can someone help me, please?

try this Infinite_scroll_pagination
and this is example code
handleFetchMeme() in controller should return in paginate model like this model
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

import '../meme_enitity/meme.entity.dart';

part 'meme_pagination.entity.freezed.dart';
part 'meme_pagination.entity.g.dart';

@freezed
class MemePaginationEntity with _$MemePaginationEntity {
  const factory MemePaginationEntity({
    @Default(0) num page,
    @Default(0) num perPage,
    @Default([]) List<MemeEntity> memeList,
  }) = _MemePaginationEntity;

  factory MemePaginationEntity.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      => _$MemePaginationEntityFromJson(json);
}

Example GetXController
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';

import '../../../domain/model/meme_enitity/meme.entity.dart';

class PlaygroundPageController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      handleGetMemeList(page: pageKey);
    });
    super.onInit();
  }

  final pagingController = PagingController<int, MemeEntity>(firstPageKey: 1);

  Future<void> handleGetMemeList({required int page}) async {
    try {
      final res = handleFetchMeme(page: page, perPage: 10);
      if (res.memeList.length < 10) {
        pagingController.appendLastPage(res.memeList);
      } else {
        pagingController.appendPage(res.memeList, ++page);
      }
    } catch (err) {
     pagingController.error = err;
    }
  }
}

Widget
class PlaygroundPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlaygroundPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<PlaygroundPageController>(
      global: false,
      init: PlaygroundPageController(),
      builder: (controller) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: CustomAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[500],
          title: '',
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            PagedListView(
              pagingController: controller.pagingController,
              builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<MemeEntity>(
                itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                  return Container(
                     child : Text(item.memeName)
                   ); // Your Widget
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


future: fetchItems() can create infinite loop. I prefer using diff logic/bloc for the pagination.
This is how it goes
class _DTPagState extends State<DTPag> {
  /// mostly I shift theses to a bloc
  bool isLoading = false;
  List<int> myCurrentData = [];

  Future fetchItems() async {
    /// you can also return like `if(isLoading) return;` 
    isLoading = true;
    setState(() {});

    ///load data by api call

    isLoading = false;

    ///fetched items
    myCurrentData.addAll([]);

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchItems(); //first time fetch
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
        if (YourCondition) {
          fetchItems();
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myCurrentData.length + (isLoading ? 1 : 0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == myCurrentData.length) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return Text(myCurrentData[index].toString());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Yeasin thanks for help I'm using Getx can help me with it?

You can try just state level and shift the codebase, well I have some reasons not using getx and skipped it
